# How do I fix this code to sent to #reported

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

A relatively simple command that takes 3 arguments (reportedTag, reporterTag, and reasons) with the simple intent of deleting the message from *#report* and sending one to `#reported` my issue is that it doesn't see the original command and hence does not send the reported message

I've tried using the channel ids, the channel names but to no avail

```
#---Report Command---#
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def report(ctx,  reportedTag, reporterTag, *reasons):

  if int(ctx.message.channel.id) == 416164062901305345:
    reason = ' '.join(reasons)
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)   
    mesg = "Report by "+ reporterTag +  " for " + reportedTag + "Reason is: " + reason
    return await bot.say("Report recieved. Staff have been notified :)\nEnjoy your day and we'll take care of this")
    return await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel("534496148149370900"), mesg)
  else:
      print ("Something went wrong")
```

Expected result: command line deleted from #report and message sent to #reported

Actual result: "Something went wrong"

Comment: What's supposed to happen is that it sends a message like this:
`Report by @IGA for @Hoe Hoe Hoe 2 Point O Reason is: being mean and swearing lots and lots`
It has previously worked however upon adding the if/else statements it no longer sends the message

Comment: Apparently `int(ctx.message.channel.id)` is not equal to 416164062901305345. Why are you convinced that it should be?

Comment: Well in a seperate command `!channel` 416164062901305345 is returned when the command is executed within the `#report` text channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things wrong:

There's a problem in the `return` statement you used in the code. `return` *exits* a subroutine, so the line `bot.send_message(bot.get_channel("534496148149370900"), mesg)` is never actually called. So your code should change to something like this:

```
#---Report Command---#
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def report(ctx,  reportedTag, reporterTag, *reasons):

if int(ctx.message.channel.id) == 416164062901305345:
    reason = ' '.join(reasons)
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)   
    mesg = "Report by "+ reporterTag +  " for " + reportedTag + "Reason is: " + reason
    await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel("534496148149370900"), mesg)
    return await bot.say("Report recieved. Staff have been notified :)\nEnjoy your day and we'll take care of this")
else:
    print ("Something went wrong")
```

Apart from that, if "Something went wrong" is actually *outputted*, that means that `int(ctx.message.channel.id) == 416164062901305345` is false. Please check the ID and the channel you're writing in.

Comment: Cheers Alex :) works brilliantly now. And I learnt something new in the process. Much appreciated!